# How to get an ActionLink to append an / to the end of a link

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

My question is simple, how to get an ActionLink to append an / to the end of a link. For some reason our SEO team seem to think this is useful? (anyone? why?) currently ActionLink renders the link as [More about vouchers](/vouchers/guide) but they would like it to be [More about vouchers](/vouchers/guide/). Does anyone know how to easily do this without constructing my own element and using Url.Action instead?

Many thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action ("More", "Vouchers") + "/" %>">More about vouchers</a>
```

Comment: Tried this but it just adds // after the </a>.

Comment: Yes this will achieve this but i was hoping there was an easier way still using ActionLink as i will have to change this in about 150+ places !!!

Comment: Then write your own helper that will take the necessary parameters and output a link with the "/" at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an extension method to UrlHelper and use that instead of Action()

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string MyAction(this UrlHelper helper, string action, string controller)
    {
        return helper.Action(action, controller) + "/";
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this from your code

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("More about vouchers", "More", "Vouchers") %>
```

But i'd really recommend you implement one extension method per action, so you can refer to then like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("More about vouchers", Url.MoreAboutVouchers()) %>
```